# Reason for various binary relation definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am a mathematics TA for an introductory course to set theory and a student had a question that got me thinking:

Observe the following definition for a binary relation: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. A relation R from the set $A$ to the set $B$ is a subset $R$:={(a,b): a $\in$A and b $\in$ B} $\subseteq$ $AxB$.

Following the definition of a binary relation in some textbooks authors write: an element $x$ is related to an element $y$, if and only if $(x,y)$ $\in$ R.

And in another textbook (I checked out of curiosity) they just simply wrote: the statement  $(a,b) \in R$ is read as “a is related to b” and we write $aRb$.

**my question is:** why don’t most authors write the if and only if statement and others don’t? Is saying “we read $(a,b) \in R$ as a is related to b” another way to word the definition as opposed to the if and only if statement? I know this may seem like a silly question, but I just want to be thorough in explaining such an important topic.

Comment: I don't understand what you think is different between the two.  If $P$ is defined to mean $Q$, that is just like saying $P$ is true if and only if $Q$ is true but by saying it is *defined* that way has the added connotation that no proof is necessary because that is how it is defined to be.

Comment: Rephrase the first as "$x$ is related to an element $y$ *is defined to mean* $(x,y)\in R$" if the "if and only if" bothers you...

Comment: Your first comment totally cleared up my question. Thank you very much, wherever there was a disconnect between the two in my mind has been fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : " is read as " means " means$_{df}$ " which in turn means " $\iff_{df}$"

Hence , the 2 definitions say the same thing.

---

$\bullet$ Sometimes, the verb " means" has to be taken as a simple implication.

For example : " $x$ is a husband " means " $x$ is married" . Being a husband implies being married.

But it is not the case that "being married" means "being a husband" : it does not imply being a husband.

Note : Since the implication does not " work " in both directions , " being married" cannot be the definition of " being a husband"

$\bullet$ Sometimes " means" has to be taken as an equivalence, a bi-implication  .

For example " number $x$ is even " means " number $x$ is a multiple of 2 ".

This is the same as saying : " $x$ is even " $\iff$ " $x$ is a multiple of 2".

$\bullet$ In the definition of a binary relation you are referring to, " means" or " reads as" is taken in the second sense.

So saying that " $(a,b)\in R$ reads as *a is related to b*"

is the same as saying

" $(a,b)\in R \iff$ *a is related to b* ".

Comment: Ray LittleRock : Is $df$ an abbreviation for definition? Also amazing explanation, thank you.

Comment: @TaylorRendon.- Thanks :)     Yes , "*df*" used as a subscript means " by definition" .

Comment: When we see this " *df*" we know we do not need to ask ourselves the question " why is it the case that ..." , for it denotes the fact that the sentence is simply true " as a definition" .

Comment: Ray LittleRock : After thinking about this once again: how do we know that in the definition of a binary relation I am referring to “means” or “reads as” is taken to be bi conditional (the second sense you explained)?

Comment: The point of a definition is to allow a substitution of the " definiendum" ( the terme to be defined) for the "definiens" ( the terms that do the defining job), and vice versa. Hence, by definition, a definition is a biconditonal. Defining X is stating conditions to be X that are ***individually necessary and collectively sufficient ; so the conditional works in both senses***. Example: " x is a man" only if " x is an animal" and " xi is rational" ( necessary conditions); and if " x is a rational animal" then " x is a man" ( sufficient conditon).  But " IF" + " ONLY IF " = biconditional.